# Shouldn’t “if pleasure be happiness” be written “if pleasure would be happiness”?

Tags: syntax

Why is there a simple form “be” after the subject in the following sentence? Isn't it that it should be like 'if pleasure would be happiness'?

> My courtiers called me the Happy Prince, and happy 
>   indeed I was, **if pleasure be happiness**.

This is from a short story, *The Happy Prince* by Oscar Wilde.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11554/why-would-the-author-write-and-happy-indeed-i-was-instead-of-and-i-was-happy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would the author write 'and happy indeed I was' instead of 'and I was happy indeed' in this passage?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11554/why-would-the-author-write-and-happy-indeed-i-was-instead-of-and-i-was-happy)

Answer (score 2):

This use of *be* after *if* is grammatical here, but it's quite old-fashioned. You might occasionally hear it today, but probably as an affectation or in certain set phrases. This use, which most would call a subjunctive, is also often called **irrealis**. You'll find the same *be* after *whether*, where (to my ear, at least) it sounds less artificial: *The city seamlessly combines new with old, whether it be its architecture, cuisine or culture* (from [www.hotelschart.com](http://www.hotelschart.com)).

See Aarts, B. (2011). Oxford Modern English Grammar. Oxford: Oxford University Press. 278-280

Comment: +1 Your answer could be much improved by providing sources which are more official or reliable.

Comment: Reference added.

Answer (score 1):

Contemporary English speakers use the words "**is**" and "**are**" instead of "**be**"

| Sentence | Analysis |
| --- | --- |
| I was happy, if pleasure **is** happiness. | Someone who speaks English today might use the sentence shown at left. |
| I was happy, if pleasure **be** happiness. | Very old-fashioned. |

Oscar Wilde used the word "**be**" instead of "**is**" to show that the prince is an aristocrat.

Aristocrats and pirates never use the word "**is**" or "**are**"
Aristocrats and pirates always say "**be**"

| Contemporary English | Old English from the 1700s |
| --- | --- |
| pirates **are** able to operate with utter impunity in the gulf of Mexico. | pirates **be** able to operate with utter impunity in the gulf of Mexico. |
| Poverty, high youth unemployment and lack of education **are** driving factors in piracy | Poverty, high youth unemployment and lack of education **be** driving factors in piracy |
| Nigeria's Navy **is** woefully underfunded. | Nigeria's Navy **be** woefully underfunded. |
| The pirate crews **are** often made up of former pipeline saboteurs | The pirate crews **be** often made up of former pipeline saboteurs |
| The pirate said, "his life **is** immaterial" | The pirate said, "his life **be** immaterial" |
| Piracy in the Gulf of Guinea **is** an extension of the organized oil crime on land | Piracy in the Gulf of Guinea **be** an extension of the organized oil crime on land |
| The incident **is** kind of unusual | The incident **be** kind of unusual |
| The Nigerian pirates have so far focused on kidnapping crew members rather than the vessels. While the ransoms **are** lower, they **are** easier to manage than ships. | The Nigerian pirates have so far focused on kidnapping crew members rather than the vessels. While the ransoms **be** lower, they **be** easier to manage than ships. |

### Oscar Wilde was trying to make the prince sound like a gentleman

[image: LIKE A SIR INTERNET GRAPHIC / VISUAL MEME]